# XPath recursive children selection

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy, scraper

I'm using scrapy to extract data from a web site, but I have a problem with the XPath selector, assuming i have this HTML code:

```
<div id="_parent">
    Hi!
    <p>I am a child!</p>
    <span class="someclass">I am a <b>span</b> child!</span>
</div>
```

what I get:

```
I am a child
I am a  child!
```

what I should get:

```
Hi!
I am a child!
I am a span child!
```

The XPath I am using is the following: .//div[@id="_parent"]//*/text()
I know this is because  is not a direct children of the #_parent div but how can I recursively get all the children?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just use: `.//div[@id="_parent"]//text()` to fetch all text node children of the selected node. [You can test it here](http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/15576862-70e3-498a-b53f-b7d82945b8a6).

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data of an element (so, all string nodes), you can also use

```
data(.//div[@id="_parent"])
```